# One-way syncing through Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

I want a remote backup for a few ImportantFiles(TM) on my desktop computer. I set up a Ubuntu One folder so to have those files remotely mirrored. That's pretty handy since I can access my ImportantFiles through the web and across multiple devices.

The point with this setup is that if I accidentally wipe away my ImportantFiles through my smartphone, changes will be synced back and I will lose files on my desktop too. That doesn't sound safe.

I am wondering if Ubuntu One is the right tool to achieve my goal. Should I better use Ubuntu One to sync music, pictures and use something else for my ImportantFiles?

Any tips about correct usage of Ubuntu One? Any tips about my scenario and my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to treat the cloud version of these files as primary, one option would be to store them in an unsynchronised location and regularly copy them over to a synchronised location.  That way changes made from your phone would only affect the synchronised copy and not the original, and if something goes wrong with the originals you should have your last backup in the cloud.

You could either handle the copying manually, or perhaps set up a `cron` job to do the copying for you.

Comment: Hi James, thank you so much. This is a nice hint. That makes sense and I'll definitely go for it. Thanks, bye!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Git in your case. Since your files are *important*, you may also want them be version controlled.

If your files are not secret and very small, you may push them to github, it's free.

If your files are secret or very big, you may need a personal git server. You can buy an Amazon EC2 tiny instance, it's very cheap and setup a git repository there.

Comment: Hi Xie, this makes sense too! I have been using Git recently and find it very nice and powerful (maybe a bit scaring at first). It may be a bit of an oversized solution at the moment, but I'll take that into account for the future. Thanks!

Comment: git doesn't work well with binary files

Answer (score 0):

Your files are not permanently lost from ubuntu one as you are thinking if they get deleted from your smartphone...

Rather if they are found missing,they will be re-syncd(i.e downloaded)...

The files are permanently deleted only when you go to the `Ubuntu One website` and then delete it by going in options...

So you dont have to worry actually and Ubuntu One is an awesome service...

Here is a screenshot of how you have to go to the website and delete them manually-

[image]

Comment: Hi Nirmik, thank you very much for your tips! I myself think Ubuntu One is an awesome service, it's just I need some more practice.

Comment: :D  yeah...it takes some time to understand....but then its simple.. :)....Do post a comment if any further help is necessary.. :) and do accept the answer if it worked for u.. :)

Comment: Just to clarify: If you delete a file from a sync client, they WILL be deleted. The only case where deleting on the device doesn't trigger deletion on the server is in non-sync clients, which currently means phones.